# Jquery Onclick functionality not working for div, as specific loaded after sometime

Tags: javascript, jquery

For `<div class="editdiv">Test</div>`. Jquery click functionality is added in document.ready function . But `editdiv` loading in page dynamically with delay.

So when I click on the `div`. Function is not calling. By using `timeout` function is working fine.

I need a different approach to solve this functionality.

Comment: Without your code it would very difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: Where is the click event handling code?

Comment: Could you provide your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `.editdiv` is loaded dynamically after your js loading so your `click` event can't detect it and it will not work, instead you should use event delegation **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to deal with fresh DOM :

```
$('body').on('click', '.editdiv', function(){
    //Your click event code
})
```

---

If you want to avoid `setTimeout` you could use `delay` with `queue` callback method :

```
$('div.scroll-area-blue')
    .delay(5000)
    .queue(function() {
        $(this).enscroll({
             showOnHover: false,
             verticalScrolling: true,
             verticalTrackClass: 'vertical-track-blue',
             verticalHandleClass: 'vertical-handle-blue'
        });
    });
```

If you will use `setTimeout` better to use it like :

```
setTimeout( enscrollDiv, 5000); 

function enscrollDiv(){
    $('div.scroll-area-blue').enscroll({
         showOnHover: false,
         verticalScrolling: true,
         verticalTrackClass: 'vertical-track-blue',
         verticalHandleClass: 'vertical-handle-blue'
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you help me with function for certain div loading in delay. without any click function , just load function . $('body').onload(){

})

Comment: setTimeout(
        function () {
            
            $('div.scroll-area-blue').enscroll({
                showOnHover: false,
                verticalScrolling: true,
                verticalTrackClass: 'vertical-track-blue',
                verticalHandleClass: 'vertical-handle-blue'
            });
        }, 5000);
    }); --     div.scroll-area-blue area is loading in delay . So i m adding it in timeout function . Any alternative way is there

Comment: is there option to load those function without using delay or time out .

Comment: $("#div1").load(function() {
  alert("The div has been loaded.");
});  -- Alternative solution for this function

Comment: I'm not sure load could be used this way, it should take the url as first param then the callback is this is the function you mean http://api.jquery.com/load/ ?

Answer (score 1):

It is really difficult to understand whats going wrong from your question. What I guess is you are loading a specific div using Ajax or similar technologies - meaning the div is not available initially.

The way jQuery works is that, it only binds the event to the elements only available at the time the part is executed.

If a `<div id='myDiv'></div>` is not present when `$('#myDiv').click(function(){})` is called, it won't work.

One workaround is to do it like this:

```
$('body').on('click','#myDiv',function(){});
```

This registers the click on body and then checks if the clicked element is having a id 'myDiv' or not. We can expect the `<body></body>` to be present always. So the problem we had with previous code won't happen here.

Comment: Working as expected. Now time out functionality is not required even some div loading in delay

Answer (score -1):

maybe you're loading the javascript codes before the html elements(tags) are loaded.
try adding the script which includes "document.ready()" before the end tag of the body when all html tags have already finished loading.
I'm hitting targets in the dark. Hope it works for you. It's difficult to generate any solution without analyzing the problematic code......